# How to link to a header file in a C# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am just getting started with visual studio and have begun a C# project. I was wondering how I can link to a specific header file/library using visual studio or whether that is possible or not.

What I want is to be able to include a file by browsing for it and to have it appear in the using headers automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: C# . I'm just wondering if I can make my life easier with some built in VS functionality

Comment: In `C#` they're called _using directives_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: If you want to add files that are in different [namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx), then you must add a reference in one file to the namespace of the other file using the `using <namespace>` directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# you don't have header files. If you are trying to use some C++ code in your application, you need to create a wrapper dll for it. [More on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150396/import-a-c-lib-and-h-file-into-a-c-sharp-project)

If you want to use a library (dll file) in your project you need to reference it to your project.

1. In **Solution Explorer** find your project and open it up
2. Right click on the **References** item.
3. Select **Add Reference**

Here you can add a reference to a project in the same solution, or select browse on the left side to find the concrete dll you want to use.

Comment: he wants to use _some built in VS functionality_ - not `C++` code

Comment: Correct but this was very helpful.